# How do I get all the text inside double curly brackets using a JavaScript regex, including the brackets themselves?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using the below regex:

`/{{([^}]+)}}/g`

This does well at matching all text in a string that are wrapped in double curly brackets, but there's a problem when the text is wrapped in **triple** curly brackets.

In this case, it matches the first three curly brackets, but not the last one.

I'd essentially like a regex that matches text only wrapped in **double** curly brackets.

So the bold text below would need to be matched.

{**{{Text}}**}

[image: Image for regex101 test using my current regex]

Comment: **tl;dr** You can't, because the JS regex engine doesn't support recursive regexes.

Comment: You want to match `{{some word}}}}` as `some word}}`?

Comment: @ndnenkov: If the brackets are always next to each other, like in example, its just a character like any other.

Comment: @PoulBak but you can't guarantee that you'll be matching the same number of brackets on both sides.

Comment: @ndnenkov: Sure you can, like one match for 1 char, then OR for 2 chars etc.

Comment: @PoulBak and when does it end? What if I have 102301 on both sides?

Comment: In my example above, I'd like it to match {{three}} from the string, ignoring the extra outer curly brackets.  Currently, you can see it's matching {{{three}} and ignoring only the last curly bracket.  I just need to extract all words wrapped in exactly two curly brackets.

Comment: A small change makes it work: `/{{([^{}]+)}}/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
{{[^{}]*}}
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `{{`: Match `{{`
- `[^{}]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `{` and `}`
- `}}`: Match `}}`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0AIwUf/1)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to match anything surrounded by *just* double brackets, this should work:

```
/(?:{{(.*)}})/g
```

See example [here](https://regex101.com/r/B3qo9G/2)

If you don't care about the brackets at all, then this should work: You can use quantifiers to greedily match the brackets:

```
/{+([^}]+)}+/g
```

If your goal is to match the same number of brackets on either side of the word, then see these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses).

Comment: With a lookahead like `/{{(.*?)}}(?=[^}]|$)/g` it would also match `{{{three}}}` as `{three}`. As it ignores amount of closing brackets and the capture just finishes before the last two. So `{{bar}}}}` will be captured as `bar}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As per my additional comment in my original question, in my example, I'd like it to match {{three}} from the string, ignoring the extra outer curly brackets. Currently, you can see it's matching {{{three}} and ignoring only the last curly bracket. I just need to extract all words wrapped in exactly two curly brackets

Comment: @jonnoMK regex is not the best tool for doing this. The RE i mentioned will work with your example, but may fail in others like `{{b{{a}}r}}` matching it as `b{{a`.